# Unable to copy video to flash drive properly

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync, cp

I tried to copy a video file to flash drive but when I eject it and insert it again the 1.4gb video size comes down to 160mb, 320mb.

I used cp and rsync command I also tried to unmount, safely eject but nothing worked.

> Copying file to drive
> [image]

> after removing drive and then again inserting it
> [image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). While you're [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/685337/edit) to replace them with corresponding text please also include the commands you tried. Also include `ls -l` for the original as well as the destination

Comment: Your flash drive might be corrupted OR you're not ejecting it properly.

Comment: Could be counterfeit flash drive.  Several guides out there for testing them via F3.  Make sure that passes.

Comment: @BowlOfRed would a counterfeit drive change the inode information (i.e. file size) like that?

Comment: I have not personally encountered one and would not expect that (I'd think that it would keep the original size).  But if this is happening after a "safely remove", it's something to think about.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, it is not a counterfeit as I have been using it for like 3 years but a few days back I was learning about encryption and I tried to encrypt it but it failed and after that this problem started.

Comment: What is the filesystem on the drive?  What OS are you running?

Comment: @BowlOfRed Fat32 and ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Nothing seems odd to me.  Have. you tried a dosfsck on the drive?  Is the file on the drive (after the copy) readable/correct before the eject but not so after the eject?  Can you run a checksum on the file before and after eject?